# JavaEE6+REST: How do I get all REST resources at runtime?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Is there a possibility to get a list of all registered REST resources at runtime?

With REST resources I mean:

- either **classes** which have annotations such as `@Path(...)` **and** are considered by the server at runtime (so traversing all classes using reflection would not do),
- or **URIs** of all paths (REST class can have multiple paths).

*NOTE 1: I am using automatic configuration (that new feature of JavaEE 6) and Netbeans just generates an empty `ApplicationConfig` class.*

*NOTE 2: Using Netbeans 6.9, JavaEE 6, Glassfish 3. Is more information on my ecosystem needed?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)? If so, then a WADL is generated automatically at `/application.wadl`. The WADL contains a lot of information about registered resource paths.

See also: [WADL Support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/wadl.html)

Comment: WOW! `http://localhost:8080/application.wadl` really worked! Thank you!  

   *Before marking as correct, I will wait, if other (better suited for me) answers will appear.*

Comment: Link mention is now broken, but this may be the new version: [Jersey and WADL](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/WADL)

Answer (score -1):

```
public synchronized Response doSomething(@Context Application c, @FormParam("someParam") String someParam)
    throws Exception {

    // gives a list of classes which are used by this Jersey instance
    // and have REST-related annotations
    c.getSingletons(); // returns Set<Object>

    return something;
}
```